# How to create and execute an SQL update statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a table inside consist of variable like Username, ContactNo, Date, Name.
And i would like to do a update for Username and ContactNo only to the original record in the database.

How can i make use of update sql statement to do it?

Below is my SELECT sql statement.

```
public void dbData(String UName)
{
    try 
    {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/assignment","root","mysql");
        ps = con.createStatement();
        SQL_Str="Select username,numberOfBid from customer where username like ('" + UName +"')";
        //SQL_Str="Select * from customer";
        rs=ps.executeQuery(SQL_Str);
        rs.next();
        dbusername=rs.getString("username").toString();
        dbbid=rs.getInt("numberOfBid");
        //UName2 = rs.getString("username").toString();
        UName2 = username;

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception Occur :" + ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: what error does this give you? what's your table structure? more info would help..

Comment: i want it to be update instead of select

Comment: @benylim Do you happen to be a student?  This is very basic information that you should already know.

Comment: Lookup vendor's tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

And please study...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty solution: when you have modified your values, just add something like this

```
String updSQL = "udate table set numberOfBid = " + dbbid + " where user = " + UName;
ps.executeUpdate(updSQL);
```

There are however 1000 improvements you can make such using prepared statementsand placeholders:

```
String updSQL = "udate table set numberOfBid = ? where  username like ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(updSQL);
pstmt.setInt(0, dbbid);
pstmt.setString(1, UName);
pstmt.execute();
```

May I suggest you to have a look at [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/), [Spring JDBC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html), [JPA](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html)... which are on a much higher level than JDBC is.